# caught segfault, memory not mapped error

Tags: r

I am trying to find the correlation of the columns of a 1347 by 209974 matrix in R. Everytime I do it (with a simple command `cor(matrix)`, I get the message:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0xffffffffd058abf8, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: cor(matrix)
```

Is it simply because the matrix is too big?

If so, does anyone have any suggestions as to how to find the correlations, other than using two concatenated for loops that find the correlations between each unique pair of rows? (I've tried this and it takes hours.)

I already checked, and the standard deviation of all of the rows is non-zero, so I know that this is not the reason that the correlation is not being computed.

Comment: I've run into this very problem in R.  There are a number of ways of going about it, but as none of them really worked for me, I ended up abandoning R for this project.  The best answer I came across used the `ff` package and worked in parallel.  Here's the link http://brainchronicle.blogspot.com/2013/02/large-correlation-in-parallel.html

Comment: (1) Even if R is running out of memory, it should not segfault. That's a bug, almost by definition. (2) You're aware that `cor(matrix)` will calc the correlation between columns of `matrix`, right? Because there's a big difference between doing that for 1347 columns and 209974 columns.

Comment: @nwknoblauch Thanks, that's helpful. What did program you end up using to find the correlations, if not R? Unfortunately, the computer that this code will ultimately run on only has one core, so I don't think the package will be of much help.
joran, is it a bug in the "cor" function? Also, sorry -- you're right I misspoke, I want the correlations of the columns, not the rows. I edited accordingly.

Comment: @user2588829 Well, it's more likely a bug in how R handles having run out of memory, than in `cor` in particular. If it runs out of memory, R should throw an error and dump you back at the console.

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6377601/1492421    and also http://www.r-bloggers.com/bigcor-large-correlation-matrices-in-r/

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem calling function on a list DATA, with 
DATA$x <- as.numeric(as.matrix(x))
with x being a function.
I just removed the as.numeric and the problem was solved.
If it is of any help for anyone…