# how to deal with "caught segfault"

Tags: r

Using `indepTestSim` in `copula` package gives the following error:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x2971b9000, cause 'memory not mapped'
Traceback:
 1: .C(simulate_empirical_copula, n = as.integer(n), N = as.integer(N),     p = as.integer(p), m = as.integer(m), TA0 = double(N * (sb -         p - 1)), G0 = double(N), subsets = integer(sb), subsets.char = character(sb),     fisher0 = double(N), tippett0 = double(N), as.integer(verbose))
 2: indepTestSim(nrow(data), p = 2, N = 1000, print.every = 0)
 3: system.time(empsamp <- indepTestSim(nrow(data), p = 2,     N = 1000, print.every = 0))
```

I use R (version 3.0.3) in OSX 10.9.2. Please help.

Comment: Report it to the package maintainer. It would be best if you could provide him with a reproducible example. A segfault is always a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: I agree with [@Roland](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland). Similar issue in another package here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933445/caught-segfault-memory-not-mapped-error with the same suggestion.

Comment: I have duly notified the maintainer. Thanks.